# Do Leader Mods work with weapon exp?

Tags: borderlands

Does the +% Exp given by equipping Leader style mods effect the exp you get for leveling your skills with weapon types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, It seems that weapon proficiencies are based on the same experience gains as level experience, meaning if you equip a Leader Class Mod (or research perks that raise experience gained) your weapon proficiencies level up faster.

Source:

[Gearbox Forums](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?p=1861152)